# Who first discovered that some R.E. sets are not recursive?

Tags: logic, math-history, computability

Who first discovered that some recursively enumerable sets are not recursive, or equivalently that some semidecidable sets are undecidable?  And in what context? Was the earliest formulation of this idea phrased in terms of partial recursive functions?  Or something else?

Comment: Using some formalization now known to equivalent to Turing machines, such a set may have been a consequence of Church's proof of the unsolvability of Hilbert's decision problem.

Comment: Maybe.  I'm looking at [An unsolvable problem of elementary number theory](http://phil415.pbworks.com/f/Church.pdf) (Church 1936) to see if it hits the crucial points.

Comment: It should be notes that Alan Turing produced his formalization and incomputable set at roughly the same time (1936) also in attempt to solve Hilbert decision problem.

Comment: Church, Turing, and Post are certainly the main suspects.

Comment: I believe Church announced his result first using maybe the Herbrand Godel formalization of Computability. However Godel himself was not satisfied with Church philosophical claim that this captured Computability, so called Church's thesis. Turing formalization was more philosophical satisfying, but we know the two model are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: I would think Church, Turing, and Kleene, and maybe others.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. Suppose person A exhibited a certain set X and proved that it's not recursive, and later person B invented the notion of "recursively enumerable" and pointed out that X is recursively enumerable. Which of these people should count as the answer to your question? (I don't know the history well enough to say whether this situation actually occurred.)

Comment: @andreas  I will read the three papers cited by Post 1944 and see what they say, and update my answer as appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the paper of Emil Post "Recursively Enumerable Sets of Positive Integers and Their Decision Problems" (1944):

> Basic to the entire theory is the following result we must credit to Church, Rosser, Kleene, jointly.
>
> > THEOREM. There exists a recursively enumerable set of positive integers which is not recursive.

Cited are three papers all from 1936:

- "An unsolvable problem of elementary number theory" (Church)
- "General recursive functions of natural numbers" (Kleene)
- "Extensions.of some theorems of Gödel and Church"(Rosser)

The Post paper and its three predecessors are all collected in Martin Davis's anthology *The Undecidable*.

Comment: The Post paper constructs an example by defining a representation of RE sets of numbers. It shows that the set of representations is itself RE, and then constructs $U$ as the set of $n$ such that RE set $\#n$ contains the number $n$. $U$ itself is clearly RE, but $U^C$ isn't, by a diagonal argument.

Answer (score 0):

Emil Post, in his paper "[Recursively Enumerable Sets of Positive Integers and Their Decision Problems](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-05/S0002-9904-1944-08111-1/S0002-9904-1944-08111-1.pdf)" (1944).  This can be found in the book "The Undecidable:  Basic Papers On Undecidable Propositions, Unsolvable Problems, and Computable Functions", Martin Davis ed., pp. 305-37.

Comment: @MJD: Thanks for adding the link to the article.  It is very much appreciated.

Comment: That paper of Post's credits the result to a trio of earlier papers.

Comment: @MJD:  I assume that the trio of papers you mention in you answer is the 'trio of earlier papers' you mention in your comment. While it is true that these three papers are (as Post states) "Basic to the entire theory", you asked, "Who first discovered that some recursively enumerable sets are, or equivalently that some semidecidable sets are undecidable [here you should have mentioned Turing--my comment]?", I believe that it is Post who first represented the results of the four papers 'basic to the entire theory' in terms of sets (though I am surprised that Kleene didn't come up with the idea

Comment: (cont.) himself, seeing that r.e. sets are domains (or ranges) of recursive functions (whether partial or total recursive functions)--I believe, however, that it was Kleene who first studied partial recursive functions--you would have to check whether partial recursive functions are mentioned in that paper of Kleene's that post mentions).